# SetupComm, SetCommState, SetCommTimeouts fail with USB device

Tags: windows, serial-port, usb, createfile

i am opening a USB device:

[image]

for communication using `CreateFile`:

```
HANDLE hUsb = CreateFile("\\.\LCLD9",
      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
      0, 
      null, 
      OPEN_EXISTING, 
      FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
      0);
```

The call succeeds (i.e. **hUsb** is not equal to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`). But then it comes time to do what we do with every serial port:

- [**SetupComm**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (set receive and transit buffer sizes)
- [**SetCommState**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363436%28VS.85%29.aspx) (set flow-control, baud rate, etc)
- [**SetCommTimeouts**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (set timeouts)

Each of these calls returns a **GetLastError()** code of **`1`**. E.g.:

```
SetupComm(hUsb, 1024, 1024);
```

Why are operations to configure the serial device failing when using a "USB" serial device, but work when using a *"virtual COM port"*? Do USB devices not support such baud rates, buffers, flow control, and timeouts?

If this is a limitation/feature of Universal Serial devices, how can i detect that a handle refers to a *"Universal Serial Device"*, rather than a *"COMM Port"*? For example, the user is the one who specifies which port to use:

- \.\COM5
- \.\LCLD9

---

Other serial functions that fail when talking to Universal Serial Bus serial device:

- [`GetCommModemStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with error code 1)
- `ReadFile` (with error code 6)
- `PurgeComm` (with error code 6)
- `WriteFile` (with error code 6)

Which begs the larger question, how do you communicate with a USB device once it's been opened with `CreateFile`?

Comment: http://www.elotouch.com/Support/TechnicalSupport/Peripherals/CustomerDisplay/change_com.asp

Comment: Yes, it's possible your device is showing up as a USB device but also exposes a COM port. Look in Device Manager under 'Ports' and you will probably see the COM port associated with the USB interface, assuming you have the correct driver installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that i don't have to do anything with `Comm`, because it's not a COM port. The reason my `WriteFile` was failing was because i was attempting to write to `\\.\LCLD9` rather than `\\.\LCLD9\`.

The trailing backslash is critical; even though `CreateFile` returns success both ways.

```
void WriteToDisplay(String s)
{
   //Open the display
   var hLineDisplay = CreateFile("\\.\LCLD9\", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

   //Write the command
   DWORD bytesWritten;
   WriteFile(hLineDisplay, s, s.Length, ref bytesWritten, nil);

   FileClose(hLineDisplay);
}
```

Anyone using Logic Controls LD9000 USB Line Display, the above is how you write to the display.

After reverse engineering their .NET Line Display driver i will also mention that the name of the port you use, e.g.:

- `\\.\LCLD9\`
- `\\.\LCPD6\`
- `\\.\LCPD3\`

can be inferred from the full devicePath returned using the Windows Setup APIs. For example, my pole display's full device path is:

```
\\?\USB#VID_0FA8&PID_A090#6&DF2EE03&0&1#{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}
                 \______/
                    |
                ProductID
```

The rule is to check the device path for Product IDs. In my case `PID_A090` means it will be available as file `\\.\LCLD9\`. Other product IDs and their associated file paths:

```
Contains  DeviceName (trailing backslash is not optional)
========  ===============================================
PID_A030  \\.\LCPD3\
PID_A060  \\.\LCPD6\
PID_A090  \\.\LCLD9\
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I can obtain the devicePath, but I don't understand where did you find the information about the DeviceName(\\.\LCLD9\)?

Comment: @lads I looked through the source code of their .NET driver. In the end it still has to turn around and call the native Win32 api functions. I just used their source code as documentation.

Answer (score 4):

No, USB devices do not use these things.  If your device is an actual USB-to-RS232 (or other slow serial), then you should be opening the COM port it associated with.  Let the drivers handle the work of sending that data.

USB communication is not like COM ports.  You can think of it more as an external PCI bus than a simple send-whatever-data-you-want line.

Comment: How does one communicate with a USB device, then? `CreateFile`? `WriteFile`?, `ReadFile`?

Comment: @IanBoyd You use a driver.  How you  use that driver depends on the device type, and the driver.